# Creating Quick Links using the Branch HTTP API?

Tags: branch.io

The links created using the Branch.io HTTP API do not appear as Quick Links in the Branch portal. The Quick Links are convenient as they show 'Clicks', 'Opens' and more in one view

API for creating links: [link-create](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/api/#link-create)

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Links created via the API and SDK do not appear as Quick Links on the Branch Dashboard by default.

If you want them to appear as Quick Links on the Branch dashboard, please add `type=2` to the payload root and `$marketing_title="some text"` to the data object on the request payload.

**e.g.:**

```
curl -XPOST https://api.branch.io/v1/url \
  -d '{
  "branch_key": "key_live_kaFuWw8WvY7yn1d9yYiP8gokwqjV0Swt",
  "channel": "facebook",
  "feature": "onboarding",
  "campaign": "new product",
  "stage": "new user",
  "tags": ["one", "two", "three"],
  "type": 2,
  "data": {
    "$canonical_identifier": "content/123",
    "$og_title": "Title from Deep Link",
    "$og_description": "Description from Deep Link",
    "$og_image_url": "http://www.lorempixel.com/400/400/",
    "$desktop_url": "http://www.example.com",
    "custom_boolean": true,
    "custom_integer": 1243,
    "custom_string": "everything",
    "custom_array": [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    "custom_object": { "random": "dictionary" },
    "$marketing_title": "Some marketing title"
  }
}'
```

Comment: I am unable to get this to work. Sending this exact payload to Branch.io with my "branch_key" creates the link in "Setup & Testing" -> "LiveView" -> "Links" but it does not show up in "Quick Links". I have tested both my 'live' and 'test' branch keys.
Is there any other configuration needed to make this work?

Comment: Apparently, the "type" property needs to be on the root and not on the data object, for the link to be created as a quick link.

Comment: I don't understand why creation endpoint doesn't require branch_secret. branch_key is exposed in mobile app, for example, and how would you prevent somebody from creation unwanted quick links inside of your system

Comment: I am having "You don't have access to this type. Please try again with type 0 (default) or 1." when I add type=2

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz the `type=2` is already disabled by Branch atm.