# How to create quick links with branch io api in python?

Tags: branch.io

I tried following this [Creating Quick Links using the Branch HTTP API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52164256/creating-quick-links-using-the-branch-http-api) , however I think there's been an update where there's no more type 2.

How do you create quick links through branch io api? Here's my current code

```
import requests
import json


def branch (medium,source,campaign,test,link):
    url = "https://api2.branch.io/v1/url"
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    data = json.dumps({
    "branch_key": '<branch key>',
    "channel": f"{source}",
    "feature": f"{medium}",
    "campaign": f"{campaign}",
     "data":{
        "$og_title":f"{name}",
        "$marketing_title":"test",
        "~creation_source":1,
        "$og_description":f"{test}",
        "~feature":f"{medium}",
        "+url":f"https://lilnk.link/{test}",
        "$ios_deeplink_path":f"{link}",
        "$android_deeplink_path":f"{link}",
        "~marketing":'true',
        "$one_time_use":'false',
        "~campaign":"testing",
        "~channel":f"{source}"
        })

    resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    
    print(resp.status_code)
```

This actually gets a 200 code, however I did not find it in the quick links.
I've checked through network where the url is supposed to be https://dashboard.branch.io/v1/link/marketing
and tried using the payload. However 403 error occurs.
How can I create a quicklink?